# Argument error when running mkvextract with PHP

Tags: php

No matter how hard I try, mkvextract doesn't work properly. I'm aware that there is a problem with the file path, but I tried hundreds of times, but I still could not succeed. How can I run this correctly?

```
shell_exec("mkvextract tracks /home/movies/R-12/X-1 ÇĞŞZ.mkv");
```

or

```
$filename = "/home/movies/R-12/X-1 ÇĞŞZ.mkv"
echo shell_exec("mkvextract tracks \"$filename\"");
```

I am aware that you cannot access the file path due to special characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I to properly handle spaces in PHP Shell\_exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378490/how-do-i-to-properly-handle-spaces-in-php-shell-exec)

Answer (score 1):

There may be several issues:

- A file read permision issue: the file exists, but PHP (and the mkvextract it runs) don't have the permission to open it. In the rest of my answer I assume this is not happening, because you haven't added any error message containg the word *permission* or *access* to your question.
- A shell argument escaping issue: correcly passing a command argument containing whitespace and/or shell metacharacters (e.g. `"`, `\`, `$`). I address this with *escapeshellarg* below.
- A filename encoding issue: correctly specifying non-ASCII characters in filenames. I address this with *mb_convert_encoding* below.

For testing purposes, make a copy of the input file to `/home/movies/t.mkv`, and then try `echo shell_exec("mkvextract tracks /home/movies/t.mkv")`.

If that works, then rename the copy to `/home/movies/t t.mkv`, and then try `echo shell_exec("mkvextract tracks " . escapeshellarg("/home/movies/t t.mkv"))`. Without the *escapeshellarg* call, it wouldn't work, because the filename contains a space.

If that works, then the problem is with non-ASCII characters in the filename. To investigate it further, examine the output of `var_dump(scandir("/home/movies/R-12"))`, and see how the letters with accents appear there. Pass it the same way to *shell_exec*. Don't forget about *escapeshellarg*.

If that works, use encoding conversion (with [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)) for the remaining filenames. You may want to ask a separate question about that, specifying the output of `var_dump(scandir("/home/movies/R-12"))` and `var_dump("X-1 ÇĞŞZ.mkv")` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "/home/movies/R-12/X-1 ÇĞŞZ.mkv"
echo shell_exec("sudo mkvextract tracks \"$filename\"");
```

I guess the whole problem was not adding sudo per :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).